# primefaces inputmask and watermark are not working? How to use it

Tags: javascript, jsf

**SyntaxError: illegal character**

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

starrs...?ln=css (line 1)

TypeError: this.jq.mask is not a function


...hBehaviors(this.input,this.cfg.behaviors)}this.input.data(PrimeFaces.CLIENT_ID_D...

2
prime faces (line 16)
Type Error: this.target.watermark is not a function
```

Getting this error while using input Mask and watermark in primefaces